# AADSTS70002 error validating credentials. Azure AD B2C Authentication for Angular 4 application using MSAL file

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to authenticate a user I created on Azure portal for Azure AD B2C authentication for my angular 4 app. But in the login up pop-up (from `MSAL.UserAgentApplication`), after entering the credentials, I am getting error:

```
AADSTS70002 error validating credentials
```

I am working on authentication for Angular 4 app using Azure AD B2C. Let me know the required code I need to share for understanding the problem correctly. Any lead on this will be helpful.

Comment: Please include important pieces of your code/configuration files in your post so that people can help you troubleshoot. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As a side note though, the error indicates that you are not hitting Azure AD B2C, rather regular Azure AD. This is generally because you're not including the policy in the request.